# CORS request from localhost using MAMP not working

Tags: cors

From localhost running on MAMP, I'm trying to make a simple js fetch request to an online website :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(link => {
        const url = link.getAttribute('href')
        const init = {
            method: 'GET',
            header: new Headers(),
            mode: 'cors',
            cache: 'default'
        }
        
        fetch(url, init)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
            })
    })
})
```

The browers are blocking the request : 
Firefox : `CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing`
Chrome : `Access to fetch at 'https://www.seloger.com/annonces/achat/appartement/montreuil-93/centre-ville-jean-moulin-beaumont/168441553.htm?ali=1&n=Ego20U46KFs_xXfggA&p=CCBPq11gAyqMJx0Q&idannali=168441553&idali=136321254&cmp=AL-SLG-Classic-new%5B1%5D-image-ALI168&pvd=SLG' from origin 'http://localhost:8888' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

I tried to allow it in the server parameters, namely apache httpd.conf, but it didn't change anything :

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    # AllowOverride None
    AllowOverride All
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*'
    Header set Vary 'origin'
</Directory>
```

My website is running on Kirby CMS. I added these lines in the config.php :

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type, authorization, origin, x-requested-with');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, OPTIONS');
```

Comment: Do you control the server environment for `https://www.seloger.com/annonces/achat/appartement/montreuil-93/centre-ville-jean-moulin-beaumont/168441553.htm`? And is that where you made the Apache httpd.conf shown in the question?

Comment: no… no way to make an AJAX request to a domain that I don't control ?